# a form of do until in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a ul

```
<ul id="variants">
      <a href="#" class="add_options right" data-id="70281696560900'>Add more </a>
      <input type="text" class="cat_name" onClick="prop()">
      <li class="current">
           <input id="product_variants_attributes_1371725880992_name" size="30" type="text">
      </li>  
      <li class="current"> 
           <input id="product_variants_attributes_1371725883311_name" name="product[variants_attributes][1371725883311][name]" size="30" type="text"> 
      </li>
      <li> Add more link allows you to add more li's(options) </li>

      <input type="text" class="cat_name" onClick="prop()">
      <li class="current">
           <input id="product_variants_attributes_1371725880992_name" size="30" type="text">
      </li>  
      <li class="current"> 
           <input id="product_variants_attributes_1371725883311_name" name="product[variants_attributes][1371725883311][name]" size="30" type="text"> 
      </li>
</ul>
```

The onclick function `prop()` takes the value of what is entered into that input(`cat_name`), now i want to populate only the li input fields before the next input with class `cat_name` with its  value (`.cat_name.val()`). So basically, it ignores the fields after the next `.cat_name` and only populates the li's input field before it with its value.
Hence populate all the li->input text until the next one. It must not populate any li->input before it just between it and the next one.

How would you go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the value of the next 2 inputs you can use  [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method for selecting the next sibling `li` elements until the next `input` element with class of `cat_name`:

```
$('input.cat_name').blur(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('input.cat_name') 
           .find('input[type=text]') 
           .val(this.value);
});
```

There is also `.prevUntil()` API that selects the previous siblings until the specified selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/mDfQT/

Comment: Thanksss, didn't know about nextUntil. thanks a lot for your help, i'll try it now.

Comment: Bless,thanks a lot, it worked like a charm, seems like someone doesn't like you lol downvoting even when your answer is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function prop() {
        //get the current input
        var source = $(this.event.currentTarget);
        //foreach sibling of this input until the next .catImage
        source.nextUntil('.cat_name').each(function () {
        //set the value of the input elements to source value
            $(':input', $(this)).val(source.val());
        });
    }
```

using jquery